# ZendAMF returning invalid XML and causing BadVersion error when called method from Flash

Tags: php, xml, flash, zend-framework

I am trying to use ZendAMF to do remote method calls to a MySQL database from Flash and I keep recieving the NetConnection.Call.BadVersion error.

My Server is working correctly. Apache 2.2.14

My PHP is working correctly. PHP 5.2.11

My Database is working. MySQL 5.0

**UPDATE: My first problem was a security error in Flash. If you try to run a local SWF from the Flash IDE to a web service online, you'll get a security warning which will throw the BadVersion error. However, the security error won't show up if you 'TEST MOVIE' so it took me a while to realize that. I changed my testing process to remove this variable. I am now able to implement my php class code successfully using AMFPHP, which essentially rules out my class as the issue (I think). It seems to be a problem with the Zend implemntation of AMF.**

I have followed a tutorial from Lee Brimlow here: http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=90 . I was unable to get this to work locally, and I've moved my content onto a web server and can call the Class and Method from my SWF.  I've used Charles to view the response. When I go to validate the response in Charles I get this:

```
Validator: Failed to Parse XML Document.
Reason: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x0) was found in the CDATA section.
Line: 65 Column: 87
```

Any ideas how to fix this?  Can it be handled in PHP?

Here is my ZendAMF code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set("display_errors", "on");
ini_set("include_path",  "./frameworks");
require_once 'Zend/Amf/Server.php';
require_once 'Animal.php';
$server = new Zend_Amf_Server();
$server->setClass("Animal");
$server->setProduction(false);
$response = $server->handle();
echo $response;

?>
```

Here is my PHP Class code: (note no closing ?> tag.)

```
<?php

class Animal
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        include "dbinfo.inc.php";
        $linkID = mysql_connect('localhost', $username, $password) or die("Could not connect to host.");
        mysql_select_db($database, $linkID) or die( "Unable to select database.");
    }

    public function getAnimalQuotes()
    {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM AnimalQuotes");
        $t = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            array_push($t, $row);
        }
        return $t;
    }
}
```

I've updated my Flash Player to 10.1. 
I'm publishing my swf to Flash 10/AS3.

I'm still getting this error when I run my SWF.

```
Error #2044: Unhandled NetStatusEvent:. level=error, code=NetConnection.Call.BadVersion
at ZendAMF_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
```

Here is my AS3 code:

```
import flash.net.*;
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc.connect("http://www.pbjs.com/2010/");
var res:Responder = new Responder(onResult, onFault);
nc.call("Animal.getAnimalQuotes", res);
function onResult(e:Object):void
{
    trace (e);
}
function onFault(e:Object):void
{
    for (var i in e){
        trace(e[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ready for this?!  The Zend Framework gateway file cannot have any space before the opening PHP tag or the AMF response will be invalid.

My only issue was that I had nothing on line 1 and my opening PHP tag on line 2.

That was the  issue.  Working Code below!

```
<?php  // MAKE SURE THIS IS LINE 1

// Configurable values
// Debugging values
$debug = true;                             // Debugging status
if ($debug)
{
    // Report all errors, warnings, interoperability and compatibility
    error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT );
    // Show errors with output
    ini_set( "display_errors" , "on");
}
else
{
    error_reporting(0);
    ini_set("display_errors", "off");
}

// Add the Zend AMF installation folder to PHP include path
ini_set( "include_path",  "./frameworks/library");

// Instantiate the Zend Amf server
require_once( "Zend/Amf/Server.php" );
require_once("Animal.php");

$server = new Zend_Amf_Server();
$server->setClass("Animal");

// Return the handle.
$response = $server->handle();
echo $response;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

does the connection work in the standalone player? check the logs of your client and see the errors that are thrown. the IDE connects in a different manner to the standalone and it might be throwing a security error.

Comment: It turns out that a security error was one of the problems. I was able to isolate and test AMFPHP with essentially the same class and it worked exactly as I expected. However, I am still unable to get the ZendAMF to return expected results.  I wonder if the Zend AMF implementation has a bug somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your PHP code? The NetConnection.Call.BadVersion error is a typical error if your PHP code has an error. Before debugging the Flash side, be 100% sure that your PHP code is working and returning the results you expect.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what all the forums/blogs are saying, however I can verify that it's working by using the same class in AMFPHP without error.